# PHP - Generate a round number according to another number

Tags: php

How can generate a round number according to a number in PHP?

Ex: if my number is

`235112`, then I should get `300000` or

`122432`, then I should get `200000` or

`328522`, then I should get `400000` ?

Comment: this looks like ceiling not round. isn't it?

Comment: Oh.. yes... how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function to have the round-up:

```
function roundup ($value, $places=0) {
  if ($places < 0)
  { 
     $places = 0; 
  }
  $mult = pow(10, $places);
  return ceil($mult*$value)/$mult;
}
```

and use it like `roundup($value,-5);` to roundup 5 digits

Answer (score 0):

String approach :

**$s** as string input

```
$s = ($s[0] === '9' ? '1' . str_repeat('0', strlen($s)) : (((int)$s[0]) + 1) . str_repeat('0', strlen($s) - 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

modified version of Gardax answer:

```
<?php
$str = "328522";

    function ceiling($number)
    {

        $strlen = strlen($number);

        $significance = "1";
        for($i=0; $i<($strlen-1);$i++)
        {
           $significance .= "0"; 
        }
        return ( is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (ceil($number/$significance)*$significance) : false;
    }


echo ceiling($str); 

?>
```